# How do I compute statistics regarding hosts like OS version using Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to obtain some kind of statistics regarding OS version or another property of the hosts in asible.

Ideally I would like to obtain something like:

```
debian 8 - 10 machines
debian 7 - 5 machine
centos 7 - 1 machine
```

Answer (score 0):

To get it in exactly this format will be hard with Ansible. I think your best bet there would be to create a custom callback plugin. Otherwise you'll always have the Ansible typical output format of tasks and their states etc

If the format does actually not matter so much and you just want the information, you can do something like this:

```
- group_by: key=sys_{{ ansible_distribution }}_{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}

- debug: msg="{{ groups[item] | length }}"
  with_items: groups
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
  when: item | match("^sys_")
```

That will output something like this:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [some.host -> localhost] => (item=sys_Debian_8) => {
    "item": "sys_Debian_8", 
    "msg": "10"
}

ok: [some.host -> localhost] => (item=sys_Debian_7) => {
    "item": "sys_Debian_7", 
    "msg": "2"
}
ok: [some.host -> localhost] => (item=sys_CentOS_7) => {
    "item": "sys_CentOS_7", 
    "msg": "1"
}
```

Since the debug task loops over all groups known to Ansible it also will loop over all the groups you defined in your inventory plus `all` and `ungrouped`. The example above filters this (`when: item | match("^sys_")`) but the skipped items will still be visible as skipped tasks.

But if you have a fixed set of groups you could simply filter those:

```
with_items: groups | difference(['all', 'ungrouped', 'all-your-other-groups-here'])
```